# How to quickly create Drupal 7 Installation profiles / Distributions

Tags: 7, distributions

Dose anyone know how to make quickly and easy installation proflies for drupal 7?
Something like [this](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/5-step-drupal-distributions) 5 easy step tutorial but for drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really helped me.

[How to Write a Drupal 7 Installation Profile](http://drupal.org/node/1022020) http://drupal.org/node/1022020